# Use vim color scheme as CSS style

Tags: css, vim

I am writing a documentation page on my site, and there is some parts of code on the page, so I would like to use the same color scheme I use on my vim to this parts (in the case, Bad Wolf). I found this site http://highlightjs.org/ but they don't have this specific color scheme (Bad Wolf). Is there any way to use this color scheme as CSS? or convert the .mvim file to css?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/honza/vim2pygments

Answer (score 1):

this may not a clean solution for you, but you may give it a try.

vim has `:TOhtml` command (read help doc for details), it can generate a HTML page for your buffer with style (css).

You can tun the generated html/css codes.

Answer (score 0):

> or convert the .mvim file to css?

To convert Vim color schemes, you can use this plugin
[ColorScheme2CSS](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5996)

Install it and type the command in Vim `:TOcss`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).